# JS Removing non-alphabetic characters with "new RegExp()" from string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a search input that allows me to filter the results of a list based on what the user inputs.
Although I want to remove all non-alphabetic characters both from the search input and from the list as well I guess, so they can find the match.

This is what I currently have:

```
let searchInput = '' // whatever the user types

let result = list.filter(element => element.name.match(new RegExp(searchInput, 'i')))
    .sort((a, b) => true * a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace non word characters with the regex `/[\W_]+/`.

It's not clear whether you trying to replace the existing data or make a new filtered list. I'll assume the later.

First use `map()` to make a list with the non-words characters removed, then remove the non-word characters from the search input. Then just filter. You can chain them up if you like:

```js
let searchInput = 'he*(llo' // whatever the user types

let list = [
   {name: '#hello'},
   {name: 'he$llo'},
   {name: 'someevalue'},
   {name: 'what'},
   {name: 'hello%'}

]

let re = new RegExp(/[\W_]+/i)
let cleaned_list = list.map(i => (i.name = i.name.replace(re, ''), i))
let cleaned_input = searchInput.replace(re, '')
let result = cleaned_list.filter(element => element.name.match(new RegExp(cleaned_input)))

console.log(result)
```

If you only want to match based on the strings without non-character words, but want the original terms in your final result, don't clean the list first, just clean each element as you filter:

```js
let searchInput = 'he*(llo' // whatever the user types

let list = [
   {name: '#hello'},
   {name: 'he$llo'},
   {name: 'someevalue'},
   {name: 'what'},
   {name: 'hello%'}

]
let re = new RegExp(/[\W_]+/i)
let cleaned_input = searchInput.replace(re, '')
let result = list.filter(element => element.name.replace(re, '').match(new RegExp(cleaned_input)))
console.log(result)
```